# Jquery accessing an element in Approval Task Form

Tags: jquery, task-list, approval-process

I've been dealing with an error I can't solve.

I've got an approval task form in which I want to hide the ribbon depending on the value of a field.

The HTML generated when clicking the task link:

```
... other code... 
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
            <h3 class="ms-standardheader"><nobr>...</nobr></h3>
        </td>
        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
            <h3 class="ms-standardheader"><nobr>...</nobr></h3>
        </td>
        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">... </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
            <h3 class="ms-standardheader"><nobr>...</nobr></h3>
        </td>
        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">27/02/2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
            <h3 class="ms-standardheader"><nobr>...</nobr></h3>
        </td>
        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody" id="tdResultado">Approved</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My Script:

```
    <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    ...
<script src="../SiteAssets/scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("x");

        var x1;

        function x() {
            alert($('#tdResultado'));
        }

    </script>

</asp:Content>
```

Shows me [object Object].

But when I try to Access its val(), innerHTML(), innerText() or any other property it never returns me the value ("Approved"), it always returns blank.

Everything I'am doing is under Chrome. 
Any ideas? 
Thank you

Comment: You get `[object Object]` because you are looking at the toString of the jQuery object. If you use `console.log`, or a breakpoint, you will see the actual array, then you can even right click and reveal the element (if found) in the elements tab, jay

Comment: Hi @eirikb thank you for your reply. I did as you say and now in the console I see the object and its properties are correct (i.e. InnerText has the value "Approved"). But when I do: `console.log($('#tdResultado').innerText());` I get an error : "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". I've used both `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push()` and `document.ready()...` but the result is always that error.

Comment: `innerText` is a _property_ on HTMLNodes, not a function on a jQuery object, perhaps you are looking for [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: You were absolutely right, now I've got it solved. If you would like to post your reply as an answer I would gladly mark it as correct. Thank You very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `[object Object]` because you are looking at the toString of the jQuery object. If you use `console.log`, or a breakpoint, you will see the actual array, then you can even right click and reveal the element (if found) in the elements tab.

Furthermore you can't call `innerText` on a jQuery object, what you are looking for is [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/).